# How to turn a SWF into a GIF?

Tags: flash, gif, animated-gif

I am renovating an old website and I want to turn the swf files into animate gifs. I do not have any original artwork and it's in an old flash format so cs5 isn't importing it correctly.
Is it possible to convert it into a gif and save it? I can use php, coldfusion and Java. Thanks

Comment: If this is a one-time operation, google search for "flash to animated gif convert" gives plenty of options in it's very first resulting entry.

Comment: The programs I would find my googling do not work on certain flash files that are triggered by events such as onload. Unfortunately all I have are said files, and yes I have tried several programs. I was looking for a solution that uses screen captures and frame steps.